# Irreducibility of unitary representation associated with a positive definite function

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have a positive definite function $u$ (with $u(e)=1$) on $S_4$. Theory says it must be of the form:
$$u(\sigma)=\langle\xi,\rho(\sigma)\xi\rangle$$
for some unitary representation $\rho:G\rightarrow B(\mathsf{H})$ and unit vector $\xi\in\mathsf{H}$.

Suppose that:
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_4}u(\sigma)=\left\langle\xi,\sum_{\sigma\in S_4}\rho(\sigma)\xi\right\rangle=0.$$

Can I conclude that $\rho$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can answer this question or complex representations of finite groups.

Note that $p=\frac{1}{n!}\sum \rho(g)$ projects a rep $V$ onto its invariants $V^G$. Suppose $d=\dim V^G$ and $U$ is a complementary invariant subspace (containing all nontrivial irreps) to $V^G$ with $r=\dim U$. Then $n!p$ has block-diagonal form $n!I_d\oplus 0_r$, and then $w=\sum u(g)=n!\|p(\xi)\|^2$. Thus, your sum $w$ is $0$ exactly when the trivial-rep component of $\xi$ vanishes, or $p(\xi)=0$.

Comment: Ah yes, the orthogonality of matrix elements viewed as functions $G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$... being non-trivial means being orthogonal to the constant $1_G$ which means the sum being zero... thanks.